# How to dynamically obtain numeric part of userform control name - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have 2 small lists of combo boxes.  The first list is labled Type(1-5).  The second list is labled Products(1-5).  I want to populate each PRODUCT box pending on the selection made in the corresponding TYPE box.  I am currently doing the following...

```
Private Sub Type1_Change()
    NavComboPropChange
End Sub

Sub NavComboPropChange()
    If BaseActiveControl.Name = "AVM" Then
         = Worksheets("Setup").Range("AVM").Value
    ElseIf BaseActiveControl.Name = "Appraisal" Then
         = Worksheets("Setup").Range("APPRAISAL").Value
    Else
         = Worksheets("Setup").Range("TITLES").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

***BaseActiveControl.name*** grabs the root control element currently selected.  Before the equal sign in the IF, ElseIf, Else sequence would be the product name and the corresponding value.

To restate my question though, I want to know how I can grab the numeric part of the control name to use in conjunction with the product box name.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using this route.

```
Sub NavComboPropChange()
    Dim myString As String
    myString = Right(BaseActiveControl.Name, Len(BaseActiveControl.Name) - 4)
    If BaseActiveControl.Value = "AVM" Then
        Controls("Products" & myString).List = Worksheets("Setup").Range("AVM").Value
    ElseIf BaseActiveControl.Value = "Appraisal" Then
        Controls("Products" & myString).List = Worksheets("Setup").Range("APPRAISAL").Value
    Else
        Controls("Products" & myString).List = Worksheets("Setup").Range("TITLES").Value
    End If
End Sub
```